# Live Sass Compiler is not working, files are somehow not linked?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I am using the Live Sass Compiler plugin for VScode, and when I start to watch, I get a strange terminal error and the files won't link.  It all seems to be linked properly if the compiler were to work, but the .html file won't update with my custom.scss changes.
The terminal warning says something about in the bootstrap files, and I think that may be part of it?

This is my index.html head:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/custom.css">
    <title>New Document</title>
</head>
```

And my:
[custom.scss file and the terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PP1k.png)

Not sure what to do at this point?

Comment: I think you are missing few sass files. Try installing bootstrap again using npm

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in the head tag and try again.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that and then changed my boostrap imports to include all of them with @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)